# flatten list of dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, merge

So I have the following list of lists, and I'm trying to reduce the size by merging duplicates only if the lists items match exactly. order is significant (changing items order will be an issue). also they are not equal-sized lists.

Example:

```
List = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], ["a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["a", "b"]]
```

I'm expecting the following output:

```
List = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], ["a"]]
```

this is the code:

```
def consolidate(all_list):
    a = {}
    for v in all_list:
        if len(v) > 0:
            k = v[0]
            if k not in a: a[k] = []
                a[k].append(v[1:])
    for k in a:
        a[k] = consolidate(a[k])
    return a
```

However, it does not seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/4518341) - though avoid the solutions that use dicts or sets since lists aren't hashable

Comment: Is the order of the top-level list important? If it is, on Python >3.7, you can do: `list(map(list, dict.fromkeys(map(tuple, data))))`, and you can leave out the final mapping back to lists too.

Comment: @wjandrea you can easily convert to tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do :

```
output = []
for x in List:
    if x not in output : output.append(x)
output
```

**Output**

> [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['a']]